# CanSum Dynamic Programming C# memoization is still slow

Tags: c#, dynamic-programming

I am trying to learn dynamic programming and I am following a 5h tutorial from freecodecamp but he is using js, and obj in js is easy with indexing, in C# I am trying to use dictionary
and I have to use `.ContainsKey` twice which I think is expensive on the performance.

```
public bool CanSum(int n, int[] numbers, Dictionary<int, bool> memo)
{
    if (n == 0) return true;
    if (n < 0) return false;

    if (memo.ContainsKey(n))
        if (memo[n]) return true;

    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        var sum = n - numbers[i];

        if (CanSum(sum, numbers, memo))
        {
            if (!memo.ContainsKey(sum))
                memo.Add(sum, true);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

How can I improve this? Is there a possibility to use an array?

Edit: Ok I did learn something new, I can new Dictionary as an empty object, like this `new() { }`

And code is like this:

```
if (memo.ContainsKey(n))           
     return memo[n];

if (n == 0) return true;
if (n < 0) return false;

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    var sum = n - numbers[i];

    if (CanSum(sum, numbers, memo))
    {
        memo[n] = true;
        return true;
    }
}

memo[n] = false;

return false;
```

Comment: You can test the key and get the value in one operation; `if (memo.TryGetValue(n, out var ret)) return ret;`. Testing for `<=0` will be faster than a dictionary lookup, you should do that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the golden rule of optimization is to *measure*. So if you say things like "think is expensive" you should first learn how to actually check your assumptions. Because even experienced programmers are often wrong when they assume things about performance. There are several possible tools for doing measurements, Stopwatch is the simplest and most basic one, a performance profiler would give you the most data, and Benchmark .Net should be the most accurate one.

> Is there a possibility to use an array?

If the range of numbers are limited you can use an array. If `n` can be any `int` you would need a large array. Arrays should in general be faster than dictionaries, but se the first paragraph about assumptions. I'm guessing elements in your array need to have three states, true, false and unknown, aka [trilean or ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).

I would also be a bit wary about toy examples like this. First of all because I do not think they represent common problems very well. Second because techniques like "don't redo expensive calculations" should be applicable to many problems. And third, things like dictionary vs array is a type of micro-optimization (i.e. both have constant access time), but this is a large and complex topic in itself, and I would argue, more generally applicable than "dynamic programming".

Comment: Thank you, you didn't have a code solution and this is the way it should be for interview questions, I am preparing and I need more knowledge than answers.

Comment: I did the assumption because I don't know exactly how `.ContainsKey` is implemented and I assumed is maybe a Binary search, and doing searching each time would be expensive. I am really new to DP, I haven't even reached the tabulation topic yet. Problem was that I didn't really understood exactly what I was doing, until I used the debugger and I realized I don't need a `.ContainsKey` in the for loop. And I figured I can instantiate `Dictionary` with an empty object, I didn't knew that was possible. After these two changes, big inputs worked instantly.